# Karate Test Framework -Storing credentials outside of github

Tags: karate

I have Karate Tests for the APIs which are on Amazon API Gateway. As such, in my Karate Tests I have to provide `client_id` and `client_secret` for authentication. I was wondering if there is a way I could store the credentials outside my github repository and use it at run time. Is it possible to do that in Karate ?

Here is how my tests look like:

```
Feature: API Test all endpoints using Karate

  Background:
    * configure ssl = true
    * url baseUrl
    * def res = (env == 'qa'? 'classpath:endpoints/user-login.feature' : 'classpath:endpoints/user-login-dev.feature')
    * def token = call read(res)
    * def headerData = {Authorization: #(token.nextGen),Accept: 'application/json;v=1'}
    * headers headerData
```

Here is the user-login.feature file

```
Feature: API Test using Karate

  Background:
    * configure ssl = true

    Scenario: Get authorization header
      Given url 'https://api.cloud.xyz.com/oauth2/token?client_id=****&client_secret=****&grant_type=client_credentials'
      When method get
      Then status 200
      And def tokenType = response.token_type
      And def accessToken = response.access_token
      * def nextGen = tokenType + ' '+ accessToken
      * def headerData = {Authorization: nextGen,Accept: 'application/json;v=1'}
```

Any pointers on how I can have the `client_id` and `client_secret` passed to the tests at run time and not stored in github.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use cyberark or similar , I personally will not prefer loading it from commandline. Maybe loading it from java code (for example pass it in to the runner class as a parameter)is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass them as Java system properties via the command-line, which you can very easily do from a test or from a CI triggered run.

Refer to the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-port-numbers

An example of how it could look like in your case:

```
Given url 'https://api.cloud.xyz.com/oauth2/token'
And param client_id = karate.properties['client.id']
And param client_secret = karate.properties['client.secret']
And param grant_type = 'client_credentials'
```

And on the command-line:

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dclient.id=**** -Dclient.secret=**** -Dkarate.env=qa"
```